# Captions in figures in MO posts

Tags: support

When posting a figure in a question or answer, is there some way of puting a caption in the figure?
When typing smt inside the brackets:

> [![enter image description here][1]....

no caption appears. (In fact any text placed inside the brackets does not appear at all).
Am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: I don’t think markdown has support for image captions. The “image description” in square brackets is the alt text of the image. You can also have tooltips, as explained in the editing help.

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek: thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to simulate captions, which I used in [this MO posting re random shape rotations](https://mathoverflow.net/q/265431/6094):

---

```
<hr />
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
[![FixedC0][1]][1]
<br />
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
<sup>
Rotation center $c_0$ fixed to centroid of $R_0$: $\rightarrow$ disk.
(Scale changes frame-to-frame.)
</sup>
<hr />
```

---

The &nbsp; are non-breaking spaces to indent a bit.
The <br /> starts a newline. <sup> is a supremum exponent—smaller font.

Tedious, but works within the limited options available to us.

Comment: nice trick! thank you very much!

Comment: I have utilized your code at http://mathoverflow.net/a/264727/85967. thanks once again!

Answer (score 5):

There is no support for image captions in markdown.

The value you enter renders as a alt attribute on the image, not a caption.

This is the text shown if the image fails to upload.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. But -please excuse in advance my ignorance on programming concepts- wouldn't it be quite easy and useful to include such a feature (captions in figures) in the posts of the stackexchange communities?